# MySQL query question

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains many rows. The table structure is as follows:

```
id: bigint,
event_type: int,
total: int
```

Sample data:

```
id    event_type    total
1      1            NULL
2     -1            NULL
3      1            NULL
4      1            NULL
5      1            NULL
6     -1            NULL
7     -1            NULL
8     -1            NULL
```

The event_type will be either `1` or `-1`. The `total` will be initially set to `NULL`. Is there any simple SQL query that will be accumulate the values of `event_type` in `total`. So, the table will look like:

```
id    event_type    total
1      1            1
2     -1            0
3      1            1
4      1            2
5      1            3
6     -1            2
7     -1            1
8     -1            0
```

Also, the `total` column can be partially calculated. In other words, I need to run the query while the table is still being modified (by insertions). I know it can be done using PHP or perl code. However, it would be nice to do it just using SQL queries.

Comment: You want a running total? Why don't you just SUM(event_type) and use a LIMIT for how many rows you want

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It doesn't seem to fit the relational model.

Comment: I want to graph these values. Do you suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since indeed MySql does not allow to update a table you are reading from, you can do it with a temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT a.id, SUM(b.event_type) AS tot 
FROM your_table a 
LEFT JOIN your_table b ON b.id <= a.id
GROUP BY a.id;

UPDATE your_table,temp 
SET your_table.total = temp.tot 
WHERE your_table.id = temp.id;

DROP TABLE temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table t JOIN (
    SELECT m.id, @RunTotal := @RunTotal + event_type RunTotal
    FROM table m, (SELECT @RunTotal := 0) dk
    ORDER BY m.id
) rs ON t.id  = rs.id
SET t.Total = rs.RunTotal
```

As cherouvim has pointed out in the comments, it is uncommon to save this calculation in the db, specially if the db is an OLTP database.